# Mudar cor de cardview e text de uma listview

Tags: android

Tenho uma listview com uma card view e dentro da card view tenho dois text, eu sei como ativar o contextual action bar quando der long press na list view e como alterar a cor do text e do cardview, porém não sei como alterar a cor do cardview e text especificadamente no item da listview que foi pressionado... Como detectar o item exato que foi pressionado e alterar somente os widgets que estão dentro deste item da listview?

Eu tentei no adapter, mas ele altera a cor de outros itens...

```
@Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            TextView textClipper = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clipperTextView);
            TextView textDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);

            cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.clipperListCard);
            cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    if(cardView.isSelected()){
                        cardView.setSelected(false);
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        Log.i("CARD VIEW", "Esta selecionada!");
                    }else{
                        cardView.setSelected(true);
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        Log.i("CARD VIEW", "Não está selecionada!");
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Eu tentei usar selector do xml para alterar a cor quando pressionado, porém não funciona para o Card, pesquisando vi que é um bug que existe desde 2014 e até hoje me parece que não foi resolvido... Ele simplesmente ignora para o Card, mas para outros widgets funcionam...

**Edit:**
Não estou conseguindo fazer aqui... Alterei algumas coisas mas ele não responde ao ***OnItemLongClickListener***.

XML que é jogado na listview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/clipper_listview">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/clipperListCard"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_listitem_margin">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/cardListLinear"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_content_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Clipper text"
                android:id="@+id/clipperTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Data - hora"
                android:id="@+id/dateTextView"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity ta tab onde tem o listview:

```
public void gerarListView(View view){
        clipperListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.clipperListView);
        TClipper tClipper = new TClipper(view.getContext());
        Cursor cursorClipper = tClipper.getClipperAllLimit();
        final ClipperAdapter clipperAdapter = new ClipperAdapter(view.getContext(), cursorClipper, 0);
        clipperListView.setAdapter(clipperAdapter);
        clipperListView.setDivider(null);
        clipperListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        clipperListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            //chamado cada vez que um item for selecionado
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                int qtItemSelected = clipperListView.getCheckedItemCount();
                mode.setTitle(getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.selected_items, qtItemSelected, qtItemSelected));
            }

            //chamado a primeira vez que o action for criado
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_tab1_contextual, menu);
                return true;
            }

            //é chamado quando a action é invalidate()
            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            //quando algum item da action for clicado
            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_card_remove:
                        Log.i("ACTION", "Menu clicado remove");
                        break;

                }
                mode.finish(); //fechar a action
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }
        });
        clipperListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.clipperListCard);
                if(cardView.isSelected()){
                    cardView.setSelected(false);
                    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    Log.i("CARD VIEW", "Esta selecionada!");
                }else{
                    cardView.setSelected(true);
                    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    Log.i("CARD VIEW", "Não está selecionada!");
                }
                clipperListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                Log.i("LIST VIEW", "LONG CLICK");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Adapter:

```
private class ClipperAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        public ClipperAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
            super(context, c, flags);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.clipper_main_listview, parent, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            //if(view==null) {
                TextView textClipper = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clipperTextView);
                TextView textDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
                CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.clipperListCard);
            //}



            textClipper.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ClipperDbContract.ClipperTable.TABELA_COLUNA_TEXT)));
            textDate.setText(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ClipperDbContract.ClipperTable.TABELA_COLUNA_DATA)) + " - " +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ClipperDbContract.ClipperTable.TABELA_COLUNA_HORA))
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe

A idéia inicial que tive não vai funcionar pois você está usando o list view no mode multiple_modal.

Então, vamos fazer o seguinte:

**Na Activity:**

Remover o clipperListView.setOnItemLongClickListener()

O Long Click não funcionar por aqui pois você está usando multiple mode modal.

**No Adapter:**

Eu adicionei mais lógica para atingir o seu objetivo.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class ClipperAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private ListView mListViewParent;

    public ClipperAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(mListViewParent == null)
            mListViewParent = (ListView) parent;
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_view_row, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final int position = cursor.getPosition();

        TextView textClipper = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clipperTextView);
        TextView textDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.clipperListCard);

        /*
            SET TEXT AND COLORS AND TAG FOR LATER USE
         */
        cardView.setTag(position);
        if (( mListViewParent).isItemChecked(position)) {
            setSelectState(cardView, true);
            ( mListViewParent).setItemChecked(position, true);
        } else {
            setSelectState(cardView, false);
            ( mListViewParent).setItemChecked(position, false);
        }

        textClipper.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ClipperDbContract.ClipperTable.TABELA_COLUNA_TEXT)));
        textDate.setText(
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ClipperDbContract.ClipperTable.TABELA_COLUNA_DATA)) + " - " +
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ClipperDbContract.ClipperTable.TABELA_COLUNA_HORA))
        );

        /*
            SET CLICK LISTENER
         */
        cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                int position = (int) view.getTag();
                if ((mListViewParent).isItemChecked(position)) {
                    setSelectState(view, false);
                    ( mListViewParent).setItemChecked(position, false);
                } else {
                    setSelectState(view, true); // Creating view. If selected, keep it selected
                    ( mListViewParent).setItemChecked(position, true);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setSelectState(View cardview, boolean select) {
        if (select) {
            cardview.setSelected(true);
            ((CardView) cardview).setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            cardview.setSelected(false);
            ((CardView) cardview).setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mas no caso estou usando CursorAdapter, e ele não tem getView, no lugar é bindView, o bindView não tem position

Comment: @felipe.rce Com um CursorAdapter você terá de ter um campo na tabela que indique se está ou não seleccionado. No `bindView()` mude a cor do CardView em função dele.

Comment: @felipe.rce Compartilhe o seu adapter, a sua activity e xml que é inflado pelo adapter.. Dai, eu atualizo a respotas baseado no seu código fonte... Compartilha só o que for necessário e tal... não precisa compartilhar o código todo

Comment: @GuilhermeP editei a pergunta e coloquei as novas edições que fiz... Apenas removi o código da cardview que estava no bindView e mandei para o OnItemLongClickListener, mas ele nem entra no OnItemLongClickListener... Tentei por apenas o Log.i para testar, e ele não entra...

Comment: Tenta colocar isso no xml do listview: android:longClickable="true" e mantenha o log na função... pra vc ter certeza que foi chamada

Comment: Tem um outro porem no seu código. Na list view, as views são reutilizadas. Então, vc não pode usar elas para determinar se aquela posição já está seleciona ou não... Vc precisa manter essa info separada... vou atualizar o código para vc entender a idéia

Comment: @GuilhermeP coloquei android:longClickable="true" e deu no mesmo, não está entrando no longclick

Comment: @felipe.rce acho que seu o motivo. Como você está usando um listview com multiple mode, dessa forma, acho que o long click não vai funcionar... Vou trabalhar aqui de novo e compartilho algo depois